# error net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING (en Google Chrome, no testeado en otros)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy intentando usar [Server-Sent-Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Server-sent_events/utilizando_server_sent_events_sse) con `node` y `express`. Lo estoy usando para enviar al *front* las acciones que se van realizando en el *back*, a modo de *log*.

En la consola de `Chrome`, me van surgiendo mensajes

> GET /events net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNCKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)
>   
>   GET /events net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

cada cierto tiempo (aproximadamente 1 vez por minuto).

El código de gestión es

```
app.get( '/events', function( req, res ) {
  res.writeHead( 200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  } );

  eventsServer = res;
  console.log( 'Open Event Source' );
} );
```

En ese código establezco una variable global, para poder enviar eventos desde otras partes del código. Para estos envíos, utilizo este código:

```
...
if( eventsServer ) eventsServer.write( `data: settings new payload.\n\n` );
...
if( eventsServer ) eventsServer.write( `data: set new config file.\n\n` );
...
```

Además, en el primer código, tengo puesto un `console.log( )` para ir trazando cuando se realizan solicitudes al *path* que gestiona los eventos. Esas trazas muestran, repetidamente

> Open Event Source
>   Open Event Source
>   Open Event Source
>   ...

Las repeticiones de estos últimos mensajes son continuas y algo mas rápidas que los mensajes `ERR_INCOMPLETE_...`. Aparecen cada 30 segundos mas o menos.

Por último, en el *front*, uso los eventos así

```
if( window.EventSource ) {
  this.$eventSource = new EventSource( '/events' );

  this.$eventSource.addEventListener( 'message', ( ev ) => {
    this.$log.add( { msg: ev.data } );
  } );
}
```

Es un código sencillo, que se limita a añadir los mensajes recibidos en la lista que estoy usando para mostrarlos.

Como punto final, el envío de mensajes **funciona**; la lista muestra las acciones según las voy realizando, y si hay pérdida de conexión y/o reconexión, esto no se nota. Pero me molestan esos mensajes; estoy bastante seguro de que algo no estoy haciendo bien.

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Como elimino evito los mensajes y esas continuas reaperturas ?

Comment: No estoy muy seguro pero segun lo que alcanzo a entender estas esperando una llamada por url a `/events`, despues escribes algo en el response con `res.writeHead()` pero hasta donde tengo entendido tienes que finalizar en el envio con `res.end()`.

Comment: Eso sería si fuera una URL normal, pero no lo es, es un ServerSentEvent. Se trata de manera diferente por el navegador. Fíjate que establezco su tipo con `Content-Type: text/event-stream`, y, como digo, funciona. Es similar a un *WebSocket*, pero mucho mas simple y de 1 sola dirección. Si te interesa el tema, visita [el enlace que pongo en la pregunta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Server-sent_events/utilizando_server_sent_events_sse), en la Mozilla Development Network.

Comment: Es verdad y se ve muy interesante. Voy a hacer algunas pruebas de manera que replique lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: @Angel gracias por tu interés. Por lo que he podido descubrir, parece ser un error exclusivo del `Google Chrome`... Por mi parte, he hecho varias prueba, estableciendo el `KeepAliveTimeout` a infinito y otras cosillas, y no he sido capaz de *dar con la tecla* O_o